# A CERTIFIED DIGITAL SIGNATURE paper pg 20 - 25

Tags: encryption, public-key, hash-signature

Reference paper: ["A CERTIFIED DIGITAL SIGNATURE"](http://www.merkle.com/papers/Certified1979.pdf)

[image: Pg 20 part 1]

1. With reference to the image above which is from Page 20 of the attached paper. What is this new protocol that the paper speaks of here? What does "transmitting Yi to B just before signing a message" mean? How does it differ from the default case? How could anyone claim to be A? What does an "authorized signature" mean?
2. With reference to the attached paper, I find that the section titled "Tree Authentication"(pgs 20-25) makes references to topics that are not mentioned before in the paper. Does anyone have resources that explains the section so that a beginner can understand it. If that is not possible it would be great if someone can explain the different parts in this section of the paper.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Merkle is referring to the big space requirement of storage of public keys Yi.
The prover needs to deliver somehow the public key to the verifier just in time, but also needs to be able to prove that the public key is really theirs.

He can do that using the merkle branch from a common merkle root that could be trusted to contain all the public keys of the prover.